# Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_11: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3 (Keras)

Tags: python, keras

I'm attempting to train a genetic algorithm using Keras Dense layers. The error I am currently experiencing is:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_13: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3
```

however the individual layers are:

```
model.add(Dense(nb_neurons,activation=activation,input_shape=(x_train.shape,input_shape,1)))
```

The full block of code that is failing is:

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            embeddings_initializer=self.Constant(embedding_matrix),
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False)

    sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)

    # Add each layer.
    for i in range(nb_layers):

        # Need input shape for first layer.
        if i == 0:
            model.add(embedded_sequences)
            model.add(Dense(nb_neurons,activation=activation,input_shape=(x_train.shape,input_shape,1)))
        else:
            model.add(Dense(nb_neurons, activation=activation,input_shape=(x_train.shape,input_shape,1)))

        model.add(Dropout(0.2)) # hard-coded dropout


    # Output layer.
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation = 'softmax',input_shape=(x_train.shape,input_shape,1)))
    model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = optimizer,
                  metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

I've deliberately set the input shape on each layer in an attempt to prevent this, however it's still feeding this error. Any help identifying the cause of the error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the output of `model.summary()`. In which line do you get the mentioned error?

Comment: there are no conv layers in the code. are you sure this is the failing code?

Comment: removing model.add(embedded_sequences) seems to remove the error, so I can only assume that's the part of the model that's causing the problem.